# Expression evaluation inside AVG-aggregation

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

If I have a arithmetic expression inside an `avg` aggregate, does the expression first get calculated for each element of the table, or is the aggregate called and for each passed element, te expression gets evaluated just in time?

E.G:

```sql
select x - 0.01*avg(x*y*z) from data;
```

Comment: Please, describe, what is the technical reason for this question and what *practical* problem you want to solve? Either case results in exactly the same operations

Comment: I'd expect an error anyway.

Comment: WEll, the reason why i would like to know is ... that i would like to know, and if infact the expression will be calculated everytime, if than incurrs performance detriments.

Does the question have to have a practical application, even if i just would like to know?